# Как сделать Html::submitButton неактивным пока не выбрана radiobutton

Tags: php, yii2

В activeForm есть кнопка сохранения, которая создается следующим образом

```
Html::submitButton('Далее', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' =>
        'resume-button']);
```

и есть группа радиокнопок, которая создается в цикле foreach следующим кодом:

```
    <?php foreach ($item as $indexItem => $ItemArticle): ?>
    <?php
    if ($year != $ItemArticle->cdate_int) {
        echo '</div><div class="control-group">';
        $year = $ItemArticle->cdate_int;
    }
    ?>

    <h3 class="group-header"><?= $newsItem ?></h3>
    <?=
    $form->field($ItemArticle, 'id[' . $ItemArticle->id . ']')->radio([
        'name' => 'News[' . $ItemArticle->cdate_int . '][]',
        'value' => $ItemArticle->id,
        'label' => $ItemArticle->name
        . Html::tag('div', '', ['class' =>
            'control__indicator'])
        . Html::tag('i', empty($ItemArticle->rating) ? 0 : $ItemArticle->rating->rate, ['class' => 'control-views-count fa fa-eye', 'title' => 'Просмотры']),
        'labelOptions' => [
            'encode' => false,
            'class' => 'control control--radio',
        ],
    ]);
    ?> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

В результате получается форма следующего вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

каким образом я могу сделать кнопку "Далее" недоступной для нажатия (disabled) если на форме не выбрана ни одна radio кнопка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсказали как это можно сделать средствами js:

```
$form->field($ItemArticle, 'id[' . $ItemArticle->id . ']')->radio([
    'name' => 'News[' . $ItemArticle->cdate_int . '][]',
    'value' => $ItemArticle->id,
    'label' => $ItemArticle->name
    . Html::tag('div', '', ['class' =>
        'control__indicator'])
    . Html::tag('i', empty($ItemArticle->rating) ? 0 : $ItemArticle->rating->rate, ['class' => 'control-views-count fa fa-eye', 'title' => 'Просмотры']),
    'labelOptions' => [
        'encode' => false,
        'class' => 'control control--radio',
    ],
    'onclick' => '$("#btn_submit").prop(\'disabled\',\'\')',
]);
```

весь смысл в строчке  `'onclick' => '$("#btn_submit").prop(\'disabled\',\'\')',` Если radio нажата то свойство disabled ставим в пустоту и кнопка становится активная (`\',\'\')',` вот это нужно, чтобы php не думал будто кончилась строка), а у самой кнопки `Html::submitButton` ставим свойство `'disabled' => 'disabled',`чтобы по умолчанию, если не выбрано было ничего, то ее нельзя было нажать.